# How to remote download the latest JDK8

Tags: java

I would like to do a wget JDK8 from a remote machine. Is it possible to do that? Since the links once I agree for license, downloads a HTML file instead and not the 64 bit rpm

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @npinti Its a yum install and not a ubuntu install

Comment: Sorry my bad, mixed Distros. Removing comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a cookie, for example (adjust file name as required):

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Comment: How do you handle upgrades on such a distribution (say if Oracle updates from a certain patch level to a different one 2 months down the line)

Comment: @Rpj You need to download the new versions manually when they are released.

Comment: Should I have to do the same rpm install with the new patch distribution. Since if they release patch 35, will it update /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_31/ this location or would it create a new JDK home say /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_35. If its the latter then we will have to modify the JAVA_HOME

Comment: @Rpj I'm not familiar with rpm but I would imagine you need to uninstall the previous version and install the new one manually.

Comment: See my previous update, uninstall is not an option since my software is already using the above JAVA_HOME (i.e. 31) and I would prefer not to change the location since there is a little downtime which is not acceptable for us. I would rather install and somehow bounce the server quickly to pick up the new patch changes.

Comment: @Rpj I'm not sure. You should ask that as a separate question, possibly on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.